# seq function weird output in R

Tags: r

I was playing with R loops when I got this output

```
printLoop<-function(size){
  for(index in seq(size))
    cat("\n Index is at:",index)
}
```

And since I have started to program in R just few days ago.I here made a simple print function.I gave different inputs to this but on giving input 0 I got following output.

```
 Index is at: 1
 Index is at: 0
```

Why is that?
So I thought that may be there is something wrong in `seq()` and by passing 0 to it I got results 0 and 1 again; my question is why?

Comment: because `seq(0)` is `c(1,0)`, i.e., `seq(n)` gives `1:n` and `n:m` where `n`>`m` counts backwards, so e.g., `6:4` gives `c(6,5,4)` and in particular `1:0` gives `c(1,0)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate it a bit more for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my comment above, see `?seq`, relevant/important points **bolded**:

> Typical usages are
>
> `seq(from, to)`
>
> `seq(from, to, by= )`
>
> `seq(from, to, length.out= )`
>
> `seq(along.with= )`
>
> **`seq(from)`**
>
> `seq(length.out= )`
>
> The first form generates
>   the sequence `from`, `from`+/-1, ..., to (identical to `from:to`).
>
> The second form generates `from`, `from+by`, ..., up to the sequence value
>   less than or equal to `to`. Specifying `to` - `from` and `by` of opposite
>   signs is an error. Note that the computed final value can go just
>   beyond `to` to allow for rounding error, but is truncated to `to`. (‘Just
>   beyond’ is by up to `1e-10` times `abs(from - to)`.)
>
> The third generates a sequence of `length.out` equally spaced values
>   from `from` to `to`. (`length.out` is usually abbreviated to `length` or `len`,
>   and `seq_len` is much faster.)
>
> The fourth form generates the integer sequence 1, 2, ...,
>   `length(along.with)`. (`along.with` is usually abbreviated to `along`, and
>   `seq_along` is much faster.)
>
> **The fifth form generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., `length(from)` (as if
>   argument `along.with` had been specified), unless the argument is
>   numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as `1:from` (*even for `seq(0)`*
>   for compatibility with S). Using either `seq_along` or `seq_len` is much
>   preferred (unless strict S compatibility is essential).**
>
> The final form generates the integer sequence 1, 2, ..., `length.out`
>   unless `length.out = 0`, when it generates `integer(0)`.

So one way to specify your function to get what seems like your desired output is:

```
printLoop<-function(size){
  for(index in seq(to=size,by=1L))
    cat("\n Index is at:",index)
}

> printLoop(0L)
Error in seq.default(to = size, by = 1L) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

(note that if you don't want an error, you could just use `seq_len(size)`)

Which is simply obeying the other admonishment of `?seq`, namely:

> The interpretation of the unnamed arguments of `seq` and `seq.int` is *not* standard, and it is recommended always to name the arguments when programming.