# How to prevent slight errors in axis break locations in ggplot when using non-integer break points in scale_y_continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've encountered an unusual issue in ggplot2 lately, where axis break points are incorrect, but by super small amounts, causing the axis to display values like 0.29999999992455 where it should instead be displaying 0.3, for example. I've never encountered this problem before during multiple years of using ggplot2 so I'm not sure how reproducible it will be for others, but below is example code that causes the problem for me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Also, here's the output I get from the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EieP.png

```
#disabling scientific notation, since for some reason y-axis values were being displayed that way otherwise
options(scipen=999)
#make dataframe
df <- data.frame(cat=letters[1:5], yvar=seq(-0.3,0.3,0.15))
#make plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=cat,y=yvar)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-.32,0.32), breaks=seq(-0.3,0.3,0.1), expand=c(0,0))
```

Comment: From the scales package, add this `labels=label_number(accuracy = 0.01)` to `scale_y_continuous(    )`

Answer (score 2):

This was a *very* interesting question!  The issue is not with respect to `scale_y_continuous()`, but actually to your call to `seq()`.  Consider the output of that call is as follows:

```
> seq(-0.3,0.3,0.1)
[1] -3.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01  5.551115e-17  1.000000e-01  2.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
```

There's your problem.  What you want is to output -0.3, -0.2, ...  If you specifically type them in via an explicit vector, your plot looks fine.  So this code for your plot looks okay:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cat,y=yvar)) +
geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(
    limits=c(-.32,0.32),
    breaks=c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1,0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
    expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

That's all well and good... but what about long sequences, where you would definitely *need* to use `seq`?  There's some [excellent information in the answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235847/seq-function-weird-output-in-r) that should help, but the basic idea is that `seq` is a primitive function (I believe that's the proper term), which can be adapted to many different forms.  For some strange reason, it seems to have some issues when using the form: `seq(-0.3, 0.3, 0.1)`.  There you're specifiying the form: `seq(from=-0.3, to=0.3, by=0.1)`.  Pretty sure this is some floating point nonsense causing those issues. :P

What works is if you use the form `seq(from, to, length.out)`, where "`length-out`" is the desired length of the resulting sequence.  When you use that form, you get what you expect:

```
> seq(from=-.3, to=0.3,length.out = 7)
[1] -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3
```

And when you put that `seq` call back into your plot code, it looks identical to the "forced" sequence using `c()` above:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cat,y=yvar)) +
geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(
    limits=c(-.32,0.32),
    breaks=seq(-0.3, 0.3, length.out=7),
    expand=c(0,0))
```